# Cucumber & webrat, selecting from a radio button list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bdd, webrat

I'm trying to get webrat to select a radio button from a list, using cucumber.

I have this scenario:

```
Scenario: Update an existing article
    Given I have an article with title Big Bananas and body text Big yellow bananas are good for you
    And I am on the list of articles
    When I choose "Big Bananas"
    And press "Update article"
    And I fill in "Title" with "Massive Bananas"
    And I press "Save"
    Then I should have an article titled Massive Bananas
    And I should not have an article titled Big Bananas
```

And my view contains:

```
.
.
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= radio_button_tag "article", article.title %></td>
    <td><%= article.title %></td>
    <td>
      <%article.tags.each do |tag|%>
        <div><%= tag.name %></div>
      <%end%>
    </td>
  </tr>
<%end%>
.
.
```

The problem is that I need my radio button id to be the title of the article so web rat can pick it up from my cucumber scenario, at the moment my output for an item looks like:

```
<tr>
  <td><input id="article_big_bananas" name="article" type="radio" value="Big Bananas" /></td>  
  <td>Big Bananas</td>
  <td>  
    <div>fruit</div>
    <div>yellow</div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Any ideas how I should do this?

Comment: `When I choose "article_big_bananas"` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem now, but did it slightly differently. I have a bunch if edit links which I set the ID to be Edit_*, where * is the article id. I then have a cucumber step which retrieves the article ID from the database using the name and then follows the link with ID Edit_*. Here's my updated code:

**Feature**

```
  Scenario: Update an existing article
    Given I have an article with title "Big Bananas" and body text "Big yellow bananas are good for you"
    And I am on the list of articles
    When I follow "Edit" for "Big Bananas"
    And press "Update article"
    And I fill in "Title" with "Massive Bananas"
    And I press "Save"
    Then I should have an article titled "Massive Bananas"
    And I should not have an article titled "Big Bananas"
```

**View**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Articles</th>
    <th>Tags</th>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= article.title %></td>
    <td>
      <%article.tags.each do |tag|%>
      <div><%= tag.name %></div>
      <%end%>
    </td>
    <td><%= link_to "Edit", {:controller => "articles", :action => "edit", :id => article.id}, :id => "Edit_" + article.id.to_s %></td>
  </tr>
  <%end%>
</table>
<%= link_to "New article", :action => "new" %>
<% if flash[:notice] %>
   <%= flash[:notice] %>
<% end %>
```

**Cucumber step to click the correct edit link**

```
When /^I follow "([^\"]*)" for "([^\"]*)"$/ do |link, article_title|
  article = Article.find_by_title article_title
  click_link link + "_" + article.id.to_s
end
```

Hope that helps anyone who's having the same problem.